# d3 handling mouse events in charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to make an interactive pie chart that reacts to mouse clicks. At the moment I made it possible for a tooltip to come up once a pie slice is clicked on. But how can I make it disappear if the user clicks again on the same slice?

```
.on("click", function(d) {   
       tooltip.transition()        
       .duration(450)      
       .style("opacity", 0.7);      
      tooltip.html("<b>" + d.name + ": " + d.value + "</b>")  
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-20) + "px");    
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in your selection are objects, then you can store within each datum whether it's selected or not. For example,

```
.on("click", function(d, i) {   
  if (!d.selected){ 
      tooltip.transition()        
             .duration(350)      
             .style("opacity", 0.9);      
      tooltip.html("<b>" +  stats[i].status + ": " + d.value + "</b>")  
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-margin*0.8) + "px");
      d.selected = true;

      // deselect all other arcs 
      arcs.each(function(d, j){
          if (i != j) d.selected = false;
      });
     }
     else {
       tooltip.transition()        
              .duration(200)      
              .style("opacity", 0);
       d.selected = false;
   }
 });
```

Note that this ensures that all other arcs are deselected when you select a new arc.

Comment: you mean I need to add another property for the data object called 'selected' ?

Comment: @user3281466: something like that, yes. What does your data look like? If it is an array of objects, than the code sample I posted should work...

Comment: hey, thanks that worked but there is a small problem because if I click on one slice then click on another and go back to the first one then nothing would happen as it still remembers that it is clicked... see below: 

on("click", function(d) {
 if (!d.selected){
tooltip.transition()        
.duration(450)      
.style("opacity", 0.7);      
tooltip.html("<b>" + d.name + ": " + d.value + "</b>")  
.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-20) + "px");
d.selected = true;
  }
else {tooltip.transition()   
.duration(250)
.style("opacity", 0); d.selected = false;}
});

Comment: I think this can be fixed if when registering a click and then setting d.selected = true, all other slices should have selected made false... But I am not sure if this is possible in d3.

Comment: @user3281466: not sure I understand, can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code? You can definitely deselect all other slices, but it'd be easier if I could see to help if you showed more of your code.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if I click on slice A that would make selected = true. If I click it again right after it will go into the else statement which will remove the tooltip so that;s good. But if I click on piece A then straight after click on piece B, piece A would have selected = true anyway.

Comment: @user3281466: I think I understand, please see my updated answer and [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/D4LH3/).